# Find the variance of X as a function of n.

Tags: probability, statistics

For each integer $n≥0$, the function defined by $p(x)= (n+1)x^n $ if 
$0 < x < 1$ and $p(x)=0$ for all other x is the probability distribution function of some random variable $X$. Find the variance of X as a function of n.

I found the mean by evaluating $$ \int_0^1 x(n+1)x^n dx= \frac{n+1}{n+2}$$

Then I think I have to find the variance by using
$$\int_0^1 \left( x- \frac{n+1}{n+2} \right)^2(n+1)x^n dx$$
 but I'm not sure if this is right or even how to solve it.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you computed the mean as $m$.  The variance can be calculated from either of these formulas:
$$ \text{var}(X) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty (x-m)^2 p(x) \, dx = \int_{-\infty}^\infty x^2 p(x) \, dx - m^2 $$
(which I think is what you did).

Comment: Thanks! The second equation really helped!